# Override settings in nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, application-settings

I have a project in which I have created a settings file (right click on properties and add settings file - see below image).

[image]

I  have then converted this project into a nuget package which I have installed into my website project

Usually in the website, I can add the following to my web.config to override the settings of the project:

```html
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <section name="Nuget.Navigation" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
  <Nuget.Navigation>
    <setting name="SelectedSection" serializeAs="String">
      <value>Investors</value>
    </setting>
  </Nuget.Navigation>
</applicationSettings>
```

However, with the nuget, it is just using the initial setting that was compiled when the nuget was published.  Is there a way to override the nuget setting in my web project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the settings overrides weren't working as they have worked with other nugets.

In the end we moved the settings into an app.config file and programmed our own singleton to read the settings using Configuration Manager:

```
SelectedSection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[nameof(SelectedSection)];
```

This way we could override in the web.config using app settings keys:

```
<add key="SelectedSection" value="investors" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you don't want the settings compiled into the Nuget package to begin with. If the parent application has the ability to override the settings, the settings should probably be removed from the Nuget and should exist only in the parent application. In order to get the settings into the Nuget, send the necessary ones in as parameters to the methods in the Nuget.

Comment: The nuget package is installed and used without having to make any coding changes, If we did it this way, we would have to add a line of code every time we wanted to use the nuget package

Comment: I guess I didn't fully understand the question then. Besides, you seem to have figured out your own way to do basically what I was suggesting, so good for you.